# Disable forwarding or caching AAAA lookups by dnsmasq

Tags: dns, ipv6, openwrt, dnsmasq

Does dnsmasq running as a DNS cache on OpenWrt router have any features to disable forwarding and caching AAAA lookups? My network is not IPv6 capable and I do not want the cache getting bloated with AAAA records that can't be used by clients anyway. Ideally I don't want to have to use a firewall rule to inspect and drop AAAA queries. OpenWrt uses musl so all the typical nss configuration tricks for glibc don't work.

I want this to happen:

client ("google.com AAAA?", "google.com A?") -> router with dnsmasq -> dns server ("google.com A")

dns server ("google.com A") -> router with dnsmasq -> client ("google.com A")

Then when it's cached:

client ("google.com AAAA?", "google.com A?") -> router with dnsmasq

router with dnsmasq -> client ("google.com A")

Comment: Please, better format the question using proper syntax

Comment: Switch to `unbound` it isn't possible with dnsmasq.. (I lost 3h already on this)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1056451/configuring-dnsmasq-to-filter-a-or-aaaa-queries/1128394#1128394 suggests it is doable with dnsmasq 2.87 via `--filter-AAAA`